Intermittent 502 from nginx-ingress with node 20 backend
nginx-ingress responds with 502 intermittently for requests to my node v20.12.1 server. It affects only a very few requests, but enough to make it a problem. The log from nginx-ingress says something like
2024/04/11 14:36:04 [error] 31#31: *16952 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 151.236.206.224, server: api.example.com, request: "POST /graphql HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.244.2.151:80/graphql", host: "api.example.com", referrer: "https://portal.example.com/"
151.236.206.224 - - [11/Apr/2024:14:36:04 +0000] "POST /graphql HTTP/2.0" 502 552 "https://portal.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0" 236 2.061 [default-graphql-service-80] [] 10.244.2.151:80 0 2.060 502 1a507161d0c4ae1937f5f9cc3811cedc


2024/04/11 14:36:07 [error] 31#31: *16952 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.236.206.224, server: api.example.com, request: "OPTIONS /graphql HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.244.2.151:80/graphql", host: "api.example.com", referrer: "https://portal.example.com/"
151.236.206.224 - - [11/Apr/2024:14:36:07 +0000] "OPTIONS /graphql HTTP/2.0" 502 552 "https://portal.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0" 30 0.006 [default-graphql-service-80] [] 10.244.2.151:80, 10.244.2.151:80, 10.244.2.151:80 0, 0, 0 0.002, 0.003, 0.001 502, 502, 502 1550f8b94189eab560d37b2aebc573a0

It is related to nodejs. When we were using node 18, this https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2019/04/25/keep-alive-timeout/ sorted out all issues. When we moved to node 20, they came back again.
I have no restarts of the pods.
We spent an absurd amount of time trying to fix this, and would much appreciate any input on how to solve it
Below is our kubernetes specification
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: graphql-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: graphql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: graphql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: graphql
          image: docker.io/example/graphql:2024_04_19_15_fbd099097
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: env
              mountPath: "/etc/dotenv"
              readOnly: true
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerhub-auth
      volumes:
        - name: env
          secret:
            secretName: env-prod-graphql
            optional: false
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: graphql-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: graphql
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: application-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 30m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "65"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "65"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "65"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.example.com
      secretName: application-tls
  rules:
    - host: api.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: graphql-service
                port:
                  number: 80
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: tech@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
            podTemplate:
              spec:
                nodeSelector:
                  "kubernetes.io/os": linux
---

